# Почему на другом компьютере программа не запускается?

Tags: java

Решил перенести программу написанную в IntelliJIdea на другой компьютер.
Сделал jar файл. Скопировал на другой компьютер. Скачал на другом компьютере последнюю версию JVM и установил.
На моём компьютере в командной строке ввожу java -version и получаю -java version 1.8.0_201
На другом компьютере - java version 1.8.0_251
Запускаю jar файл на другом компьютере и получаю сообщение:
"Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"
До этого ни разу не переносил программы на другие машины.
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно у вас установлен более свежая версия JDK (выше чем 1.8), и JRE (Java 8) которая выводит в консоль версию 1.8.0_201

наберите следующую команду в консоли:

```
javac -version
```

Другими словами, программа компилируется на Java 9 или выше, а на другом компьютере стоит более ранняя версия Java 8,

Comment: действительно, выдаёт версию 13.0.2 Как же решить эту проблему? Я ведь на другой компьютер скачал самую свежую версию JRE

Comment: если у вас maven проект, то укажите в настройках <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version> и соберите заново проект

Comment: Нет, у меня не maven проект. Зашёл в IDE в настройках Project language level изменил 13 на 8.
После этого jar файл на другом компьютере запустился, но программа почему-то не считывает сохранённые данные предыдущей игры.
Посмотрел настройки IDE. Там есть пункт Project SDK и по умолчанию он равен 13.
Возможные варианты загрузки из сети:

1)Amazon corretto
2)BellSoft Liberica
3)Adopt OpenJDK(HotSpot)
4)Azul Zulu
5) Adopt OpenJDK(OpenJ9)

Comment: У всех этих вариантов есть версии 1.8; 11; 13; 14

Насколько я понял нужно загрузить версию 1.8, но какой вариант из предложенных пяти выбрать? Чем они отличаются?
Это значит, что на другой компьютер тоже нужно установить именно этот вариант? Или это не важно, лишь бы версия 1.8?

Comment: это не важно, лишь бы версия 1.8, но тут тоже есть ограничения, если на другом компьютере стоит версия к примеру 1.8.0_008 то тоже может ругаться если проект был собран на 1.8.0_251, в идеале java должна быть той же версии или выше